# Application Crashes when Load Picture in Listview from Gallery in Android

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I am loading pictures in listview taken from camera and directly from gallery. On emulator images from gallery works perfect. But on device when i select first picture it works good. But when i select same picture second time application crashes and no logcat appears.
here is a code:

```
if (requestCode == UploadFile && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Bitmap image=(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            cursor.close();

            addattachmentsToListView(image);
```

Comment: If there's a crash, there's logcat unless you're specifically catching and ignoring runtime exceptions. In this code, you should at least check the return value of `moveToFirst()` to ensure the cursor points to a valid row before accessing row data.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if it breaks without log you can try to debug it via the Eclipse debugger or similar, may be an option to better understand whats happening.

As far as i can see, your code seems to depend on the fact that there will always be a correct response with at least one result and the [0] column of that result valid.